# Html script doesn't work anymore after moving into source file - why so? how to fix?

Tags: html, src, script-tag

I got an html file that looks somewhat like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lang-parser.js"></script>
  <script id="code" type="text/some-scripting-language">
  //some code here in some language that is not js
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works and seems fine. Now I take the code in the middle script and move  it into another file, and change the html code for that to:

```html
  <script id="code" src="code.cdy" type="text/some-scripting-language"></script>
```

and it stops working, without any explicit errors, as if the script didn't load in time or something.

My question is: what can be the reason for this behavior and how can I change it?

Notes:

1. Even if I write a wrong name of the file the console doesn't inform me about non-existent file.
2. If I additionally write that the file is of type `text/javascript` (which it is not), when the console finally informs me the file doesn't exist.
3. IMHO: It looks like the language parser gets downloaded asynchronously, and while it is in the process the parser reads the next tag, sees unknown type of language there and just ignores the entire thing... But that doesn't explain why without the source the code works.

Comment: Yep... What you said is right. When it's not JavaScript, the browser won't even consider that line. It's syntax. Why do you wanna do that anyway?

Comment: See the [docs for `type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes). `text/some-scripting-language` is not a recognized `type`, so it _“won't be processed by the browser”_ and the _“`src` attribute will be ignored”_. If you want to download a non-JS file, consider using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I dunno, the working thing was there before me, I just wanted the move scripts into different files.

Comment: @Xufox that script in the middle is NOT js. I do not know how the first eample works, but it does for me.

Comment: @Xufox you said "there is no language parser downloaded", but the first script actually includes language parser for the second script. Hence I assumed you assumed the middle one is written in js at some point.

Comment: @mike239x I see what you mean now. The first script is the parser for the second “script”. Yes, in your first snippet the parser reads the `textContent` of the `<script>` (that’s what such parsers usually do with `<script type="text/non-js">`) which works fine. In your second snippet however, the `textContent` is empty. `code.cdy` is not downloaded, because a `<script src>` can only download executable JavaScript code. See if the parser provides an option to parse an arbitrary string rather than the `textContent` of a `<script>`. Then you may be able to pass a Fetch response to the parser.

Comment: @Xufox (!) that's actually pretty clever what you said there, I bet that is exactly what happens there (also that explains why there was id attribute on that script tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the lang parser js does not see the contents of your script because the element with id 'code' is empty, and the src tag does not mean anything to it